# como agregar decimales a un numero obtenido de una api?

Tags: javascript, html, css, api

hola como hago para mostrar decimales de un numero obtenido de una api?
por ejemplo si obtengo 1 ; 2,5 ; 3 ; 3,5 ; quiero mostrarlo asi: 1,o ;2,5 ;3,0 ;3,5

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

asi me queda ahora y quiero cambiar la estructura de los numeros de alicuota para una mejor vista

Comment: Si tienes acceso al código de la API, cámbialo ahí para que te devuelva los decimales.

Comment: no, solo los datos de salida

Answer (score 0):

te ayudara este codigo:

```
var number = 1;
console.log(number.toFixed(2)); // Agregas 2 decimales

for(var key in lista) {    
 //Le estas asignando el mismo valor, pero con los decimales.
 lista[key].alicuota = lista[key].alicuota.toFixed(2);
}
```

Saludos

Comment: como se implementa ? lo probe tal cual estaba y si funciona pero como puedo agregarlo para que funcione?

Comment: Hola, supongo que estas llamandao a tu API por ajax, entonces este devuelve una lista esa lista debes recorrerla y agregar ese codigo:

for(var key in lista){
  lista[key].alicuota =  lista[key].alicuota.toFixed(2)
}

Comment: Dejo código
`for(var key in lista)
{ 
  lista[key].alicuota = lista[key].alicuota.toFixed(2) 
} `

Comment: @JosepFuentes la respuesta tiene la opción para Editar; ahí se visualizaría mejor el código.

Comment: llamo a la api por metodo fetch de javascript,igual funciona?

Comment: Considera editar tu respuesta para explicar qué hace el código y completarla con lo que agregaste en los comentarios. Tal como está, no es una respuesta de calidad y puede terminar eliminada.

Comment: Si, si funcionaria basta con que tengas la lista en tu js.